# How to read text from .plist file?

Tags: python

My iPhone app has App Version number in Info.plist. I need a python script to read the App Version from it and print both?

I have printed the plist file. Below is the code

```
for file in os.walk(FOLDERPATH):
    inFile = open('Info.plist', 'rt')
    for line in inFile:
print(inFile.read())
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this.  I believe its what you're looking for.  Hope it helps!
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/plistlib.html

Comment: I think if it's not in SO, then a Q&A should be added for it, even if trivial. Ultimately, it will be the first google result I look at, like what happened here.

Answer (score 9):

Slightly adapted [plistlib](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/plistlib.html) example:

```
import plistlib
pl = plistlib.readPlist("Info.plist")
item = pl["aKey"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated [plistlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html) example for Python3:

```py
import plistlib
file_name = "/Users/Dave/Info.plist"
with open(file_name, 'rb') as infile:
    plist = plistlib.load(infile)
print(plist["aKey"])
```